# Retrieving error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 17: invalid start byte

Tags: python, numpy, utf-8, zeromq, pyzmq

client side

I have following code sending array from client to server. I am retreiving UTF-8 decode error. I don't prefer to load data pickle or zlib compress. I am pyzmq socket to send data and receive data.

```
def send_array(socket, A, flags=0, copy=True, track=False):
  """send a numpy array with metadata"""
  md = dict(
    dtype = str(A.dtype),
    shape = A.shape,
  )
  socket.send_json(md, flags|zmq.SNDMORE)
  return socket.send(A, flags, copy=copy, track=track)

def forward_data(frame, count):
   source = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(frame), dtype=np.uint8), 1)
   image = img_to_array(source)
   image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
   preds = m1.predict(preprocess_input(image))
   send_array(dest_socket,preds)
```

server side

```
def recv_array(socket, flags=0, copy=True, track=False):
"""recv a numpy array"""
  md = socket.recv_json(flags=flags)
  msg = socket.recv(flags=flags, copy=copy, track=track)
  buf = np.buffer(msg)
  A = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype=md['dtype'])
  return A.reshape(md['shape'])

def handle_image_processing(frame, count):
  frame_object=recv_array(socket)
  tmp = np.zeros(frame_object.shape)
  for i in range( 0, 1 ):
    tmp[i,:] = tmp[i, :]
    predictions_result = m2.predict( tmp )
    label_vgg16 = decode_predictions( predictions_result )
    print(label_vgg16)
```

Error retrieving
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   handle_image_processing(frame,count)
   File "C:/Pause-Resume-Approach-Updated/server-b.py", line 82, in handle_image_processing
   frame_object=recv_array(socket)
   File "C:/Pause-Resume-Approach-Updated/server-b.py", line 68, in recv_array
   md = socket.recv_json(flags=flags)
   File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 690, in recv_json
   return self._deserialize(msg, lambda buf: jsonapi.loads(buf, **kwargs))
   File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 515, in _deserialize
   return load(recvd)
   File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 690, in <lambda>
   return self._deserialize(msg, lambda buf: jsonapi.loads(buf, **kwargs))
   File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\jsonapi.py", line 54, in loads
   s = s.decode('utf8')
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 17: invalid start byte
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of an object is the `socket` argument? Can you indicate which line raises the exception and/or include the full traceback?

Comment: Thanks @lenz, I have updated the post.

Comment: It looks like message you sent with `socket.send_json` is not (or not only) the one you deserialise with `recv_json`. Is it a good pattern to mix messages sent with `send` and `send_json`? It may be tricky to distinguish this on the server side (and aligning the two corresponding messages may also be tricky in case there are concurrent requests).

Comment: @lenz both of the methods { .send(), .send_json() } were actually used to fill-in one and the only one message envelope ( a multi-frame one ), so your assumption that the server-side has to do some magics to guess which of the arrived stream of messages was loaded in which way is not materialising, yet I share your doubts that making a multiframe-message loaded with a mix of the said methods { .send(), .send_json(), ... } is both safe and efficient way how to compose an in principle many-party open-end distributed computing systems ( both a more efficient mapping + a robust defense is needed )

Answer (score 0):

While your code uses (properly) the `zmq.SNDMORE` flags on constructing the multipart-message payload before sending, the receiving part ignores any & all `zmq.RCVMORE`-driven testing, if any next part of the delivered message ought be consumed.

Something like this ought work :

```
while True:
      ...
      if socket.getsockopt( zmq.RCVMORE ):
         continue
      else:
         break
```

I have never tested a mixed methods python-code on multi-frame messages. The native ZeroMQ API is clear in this and one can read with `zmq.RCVMORE`-testing until the last part of the multi-frame message, while python ported besides the `.recv()` a set of derived method, `.recv_json()` being used here. If that port keeps the native API, the repaired code shall handle the flags as expected, if not, expect problems from some pyzmq side effects, not present in the original API.

If not happy with the pyzmq builtin method `.send_obj()`, may use a python `struct` module to very efficiently pack bytefields mapped data-elements ( `.shape`, `.dtype` ) and the *`<array>`*`.data()`-method.

Code shall also enjoy to become more robust against not receiving a multi-part, but a plain or even an empty at all message envelope, be it due to one's own human error or due to an adversary intrusion.